# Search optimum on connected simulation

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Do you know how can I find minimum/maximum of a simulation written in a Module.
The simulation calculates a potential value to a territory after some steps.

It would seem like this:

```
g[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_,x6_] := Module[{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6}, some code calling a simulator software]
```

So I would like to reach a maximum potential according to the parameters.
All parameters should vary between [-2 ... 0 .. 2], with stepsize 1 discretely.
So all variations are 5^6, I don't have so much time and resource to calculate each variation.

Can you advise me some code or algorithm where I only have to put the name of the target function?

Comment: Uh... `NMinimize`/`NMaximize`? `FindMinimum`/`FindMaximum`? Read their documentation, try it, and if you have any trouble, you can update the question to get some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define so it only exists for explicitly numeric intput, as

```
g[x1_?NumberQ,x2_?NumberQ,x3_?NumberQ,x4_?NumberQ,x5_?NumberQ,x6_?NumberQ]
```

Then can do

```
vars = {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6};
NMinimize[{g[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6],Element[vars,Integers]
    Thread[-2<=#<=2&, vars]}, vars]
```

There are ways to make this slightly cleaner, but that's the idea. The reason to define only for numeric input is to make it effectively a "black box" function, so that no symbolic processing will be attempted.

If `NMinimize` is too slow or not giving viable results, could try `FindMinimum` but I don't think it will directly accept the integrality constraints for a nonlinear problem. So you'd probably need to use some penalty term approach involving, for each variable, `(xj-Round[xj])^2` or some such.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I am going to try it and report :)